# What is the name of the theorem?

Tags: functions, continuity

> Let $f$ be continuous, $f(x_1)<0$ and $f(x_2)>0$, there has to be a
>   root of $f$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$?

I know it is very basic, but i was not using calculus for a long time, and name of the theorem slips from my mind. thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). It states as follows.

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function and let $u \in \mathbb{R}$ be between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Then, there exists a $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=u$.

Comment: @AyleanClaraGrandieur see update with full text & hyperlink